# Can you build an ASP.NET Web API on top of OWIN?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, owin

Well the title basically sums it up, I'm wondering if I can create an OWIN pipeline to my ASP.NET Web API. I want to do this so I can apply a base security layer that I can apply to all of my API service hosted on my service server. New to OWIN, love the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can start with this http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin/0.21.0-pre and then you will need an another package depending on what host you choose.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm assuming you have done this before? If so, have you used Katana. Any recommendations or nice url post, blogs you could point me to? Thanks for the help man

Comment: @mtleising Filip's post referenced below is good for Katana.  I have a post on using it with Self-host http://www.bizcoder.com/2013/01/12/experiments-with-katana/  Be careful though because everything is changing so fast, every blog post is out of date!

Comment: Filip's written an updated blog post that's more current: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/the-future-is-now-owin-and-multi-hosting-asp-net-web-applications/.

Answer (score 1):

You will find below link helpful. It using Katana, an OWIN implementation for Microsoft hosts and the Web API framework.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/running-aspnet-web-api-with-owin-and-katana/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Also:  If self-hosting Web API 2 using OWIN in a windows service, you can check out this example on GitHub: https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service

It walks you through creating the service, adding OWIN using NuGet, and using attribute based routing in Web API 2.